# How do I load an xml file into an XStreamingElement?

Tags: linq-to-xml

Does anyone have an example how to populate an XStreamingElement from an XML file?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the XML file in code or do you need to access it from outside?

Comment: No it's an external file at the moment for prototyping but will ultimately be read in from a database (blob).

Comment: This page has several examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx 
You might have to give code examples if you wan't such answers.